# $httpBackend.flush fails when service throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have created a service to serve as a client of my backend API. When backend returns an error, my service should handle that problem by rethrowing the error with more readable message to be later caught at controller level:

```
function readApi() {
        return $http.get("adress").catch(function (e) {
            if (e.status === 400) {
                throw new Error("API call not succeded...");
            }
        }).then(function (requestResult) {
            // further processing of result
        });
    }
```

Then, I tried to write a spec in Jasmine testing this behaviour:

```
    it('throw proper error for 400 reponse from API', function () {
    httpBackend.expectGET('address').respond(400, '');

    expect(function () {
        myService.readApi();
    }).toThrow();

    httpBackend.flush();
});

afterEach(function () {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

Unfortunately the error seems to be thrown from httpBackend.flush() instead my function, leading to failure of test.

Am using it wrong or is it error in httpBackend mock? How can i perform such test?

EDIT

I tried @tomepejo's answer and it *almost* worked:

```
it('throw proper error for 400 reponse from API', function () {
    httpBackend.expectGET('address').respond(400, '');

    expect(function () {
        myService.readApi();
        httpBackend.flush();
    }).toThrow();
});

afterEach(function () {
   //httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
   httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

Unfortunately uncomenting afterEach's body leads to error:

```
 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
   at .../Scripts/Lib/angular.js:63:12
   at beginPhase (.../Scripts/Lib/angular.js:14755:15)
   at Scope.$digest (.../Scripts/Lib/angular.js:14197:9)
   at Function.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation (.../Scripts/Lib/angular-mocks.js:1550:38)
   at Object.<anonymous> (.../ApiClientTest.js:94:29)
```

I think it doesn't need mentioning, that this afterEach is useful in numerous other tests and pasting those calls at the end on every test (or extracting exception testing to another describe) doesn't  feel like a *right* way to do it.

Or maybe it is a bug in an angular-mocks library and I should file a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by passing **false** to the `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` function, but in order to not interfere with the $digest cycle of other tests, you can do the following:

```js
var shouldDigest;
beforeEach(inject(function (...) {
    //your initialization here

    shouldDigest = true;
}));

afterEach(function () {
   httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation(shouldDigest);
   httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

and in this test specifically:

```js
it('throw proper error for 400 reponse from API', function () {
    httpBackend.expectGET('address').respond(400, '');

    expect(function () {
        myService.readApi();
        httpBackend.flush();
    }).toThrow();
    shouldDigest = false;
});
```

Source and explanation here: http://nikas.praninskas.com/angular/2015/11/20/quickie-httpbackend-digest-in-progress/

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `httpBackend.flush()` inside of the expect function.

```
expect(function () {
  myService.readApi();
  httpBackend.flush();
}).toThrow();
```

Comment: Well, it kind of works, but not really. See the edit of original question for further details. Thank you for help though :)